# How to fix bsdthread_register error in MacOS 12.2

Tags: bash, macos, genstrings

I have a utility for using genstrings to extract localized strings in a few sub-directies for an objective-c project like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_SOURCES="AccessoryViews/*.m Clouds/*.m CustomStyles/*.m"

cd ~/Documents/Projects/MyProject

genstrings ${APP_SOURCES} && ~/Documents/Projects/MyProject/stringsfmt -move -from Localizable.strings -to L10n/Base.lproj/Localizable.strings
```

This used to work fine in MacOS 11 but stopped working after I installed MacOS 12.2. When running it I get this error:

```
fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x13ae8e, 0x21)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95 fp=0x7ff7bfeff9c0 sp=0x7ff7bfeff9a0
runtime.goenvs()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.1/libexec/src/runtime/os_darwin.go:88 +0xa0 fp=0x7ff7bfeff9f0 sp=0x7ff7bfeff9c0
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:450 +0x9c fp=0x7ff7bfeffa30 sp=0x7ff7bfeff9f0
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ff7bfeffa60, 0x6, 0x7ff7bfeffa60, 0x1000, 0x6, 0x7ff7bfeffbd8, 0x7ff7bfeffc12, 0x7ff7bfeffc18, 0x7ff7bfeffc1e, 0x7ff7bfeffc32, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:145 +0x14f fp=0x7ff7bfeffa38 sp=0x7ff7bfeffa30
```

There are a few similar question on SO, which for example suggest changing bash to zsh. When I do that, the bsdthread_register error disappears, however, then I get this error:

```
genstrings: error: failed to read input file AccessoryViews/*.m Clouds/*.m CustomStyles/*.m
```

As if genstrings does not accept the wild cards when used under zsh ?

Any idea on how to solve this, preferably using bash

Thanks in advance,